# Playwright - Checking Class Name of an Element

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm testing a site which has a list that needs to be opened or is open already. The class of the element changes according to the state it is currently in.

So the element is either

```
div class="list-open"
```

or

```
div class="list-closed"
```

My script has to check this to make sure to open the list if it is closed to continue the algorithm. How can I check the class name with Playwright for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask for the class name of the element.

```
page.locator("div").evaluate("node => node.className")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the expect assertion like this. `.list-open,.list-closed` will be evaluated as either `.list-open` or `.list-closed`.

```py
expect(page.locator("div")).to_have_class(".list-open,.list-closed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Playwright's LocatorAssertion [`toHaveClass`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class) seems to be what you are looking for:

```
await expect(page.locator('div')).toHaveClass(/list-open/);
```

Note that either the argument needs to be a full match or you have to use regex as in the example above.